# Decoding several text files from Byte to UTF-8

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8, python-unicode

I'm currently trying to loop over roughly 9000 .txt files **in python** to extract data and add them to a joined pandas data frame. The .txt data is stored in bytes, so in order to access it I was told to use a decoder. Because I'm interested in preserving special characters, I would like to use the UTF-8 decoder, but I'm getting the following error when trying to do so:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3131: invalid start byte
```

For some reason, the code works just fine when using a 'ISO-8859-1' decoder, but this obviously messes up all special characters. Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm pasting my code below! Also, the decoding works for the first ~1600 .txt files in my dataset, but for the rest it doesn't.

```
decode_counter = 0
for index, i in enumerate(corpus[0]):
    decode_counter += 1
    corpus.iloc[index][0] = i.decode('UTF-8')
```

The corpus variable contains the name of the .txt file as an index, and the contents of the individual .txt files in a column named 0. Thank you very much!

Comment: So it means that your files were not UTF-8 (and not ISO-8859-1 aka Latin1). Try to find the original encoding. Just try one file with many encoding. cp1252, cp850, cp437 were common in Western Europe (and US) in past on PC.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do you have any tips on how one could find the original encoding?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. At least, share a code snippet (_exactly_) for the `corpus` variable…

Comment: [Detecting encodings of multiple files](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#example-detecting-encodings-of-multiple-files)?

Comment: If you know the origin of the file, it would help. E.g. what period was written (the program which wrote the file). Which operating system? Which region? Which language? Else just try. If you know the character which it is displayed wrongly, and so you know the code of such character, go to wikipedia on such character, often you see the value in many encodings, so you can reduce the set to search

Comment: Thanks everyone! I got it to work using a try except statement, essentially trying to use UTF-8 (which worked in most cases), and then using the ISO type for all cases in which it didn't work. Tysm!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try every codec available in your environment and check which result fits best.
Here is a way of doing that:

```
import os, codecs, encodings
from collections import OrderedDict
from typing import Union
from cprinter import TC
from input_timeout import InputTimeout


class CodecChecker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.encodingdict = self.get_codecs()
        self.results = OrderedDict()

    def get_codecs(self):
        dir = encodings.__path__[0]
        codec_names = OrderedDict()
        for filename in os.listdir(dir):
            if not filename.endswith(".py"):
                continue
            name = filename[:-3]
            try:
                codec_names[name] = OrderedDict({"object": codecs.lookup(name)})
            except Exception as Fehler:
                pass
        return codec_names

    def try_open_file(self, path: str, readlines: int = 0):
        self.results = OrderedDict()
        results = OrderedDict()
        if readlines == 0:
            for key, item in self.encodingdict.items():
                results[key] = {"strict_encoded": [], "strict_bad": True}

                try:
                    with open(path, encoding=key) as f:
                        data = f.read()
                        results[key]["strict_encoded"].append(data)
                        results[key]["strict_bad"] = False
                except Exception as fe:
                    results[key]["strict_encoded"].append(str(fe))
                    continue
        else:
            for key, item in self.encodingdict.items():
                results[key] = {"strict_encoded": [], "strict_bad": True}

                try:
                    with open(path, encoding=key) as f:
                        for ini, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
                            if ini == readlines:
                                break
                            results[key]["strict_encoded"].append(line[:-1])
                        results[key]["strict_bad"] = False
                except Exception as fe:
                    results[key]["strict_encoded"].append(str(fe))
                    continue
        self.results = results.copy()
        return self

    def try_convert_bytes(self, variable: bytes):
        self.results = OrderedDict()

        results = OrderedDict()
        modes = ["strict", "ignore", "replace"]
        for key, item in self.encodingdict.items():
            results[key] = {
                "strict_encoded": [],
                "strict_bad": True,
                "ignore_encoded": [],
                "ignore_bad": True,
                "replace_encoded": [],
                "replace_bad": True,
            }
            for mo in modes:
                try:
                    results[key][f"{mo}_encoded"].append(
                        item["object"].decode(variable, mo)
                    )
                    results[key][f"{mo}_bad"] = False
                except Exception as Fe:
                    results[key][f"{mo}_encoded"].append(str(Fe))
        self.results = results.copy()

        return self

    def print_results(
        self, pause_after_interval: Union[int, float] = 0, items_per_interval: int = 0
    ):
        counter = 0
        for key, item in self.results.items():
            if pause_after_interval != 0 and items_per_interval != 0:
                if items_per_interval == counter and counter > 0:
                    i = InputTimeout(
                        timeout=pause_after_interval,
                        input_message=f"Press any key to continue or wait {pause_after_interval} seconds",
                        timeout_message="",
                        defaultvalue="",
                        cancelbutton=None,
                        show_special_characters_warning=None,
                    ).finalvalue
                    counter = 0
            print(
                f'\n\n\n{"Codec".ljust(20)}: {str(TC(key).bg_cyan.fg_black)}'.ljust(100)
            )
            if "strict_bad" in item and "strict_encoded" in item:
                print(f'{"Mode".ljust(20)}: {TC("strict").fg_yellow.bg_black}')

                if item["strict_bad"] is False:
                    if isinstance(item["strict_encoded"][0], tuple):
                        if item["strict_bad"] is False:

                            try:
                                print(
                                    f"""{'Length'.ljust(20)}: {TC(f'''{item['strict_encoded'][0][1]}''').fg_purple.bg_black}\n{'Converted'.ljust(20)}: {TC(f'''{item['strict_encoded'][0][0]}''').fg_green.bg_black}"""
                                )
                            except Exception:
                                print(
                                    f"""Problems during printing! Raw string: {item['strict_encoded'][0][0]!r}"""
                                )

                        if item["strict_bad"] is True:
                            try:
                                print(
                                    f"""{'Length'.ljust(20)}: {TC(f'''{"None"}''').fg_red.bg_black}\n{'Converted'.ljust(20)}: {TC(f'''{item['strict_encoded'][0]}''').fg_red.bg_black}"""
                                )
                            except Exception:
                                print(
                                    f"""Problems during printing! Raw string: {item['strict_encoded'][0][0]!r}"""
                                )
                    if isinstance(item["strict_encoded"][0], str):
                        if item["strict_bad"] is False:
                            itemlen = len("".join(item["strict_encoded"]))
                            concatitem = "\n" + "\n".join(
                                [
                                    f"""Line: {str(y).ljust(14)} {str(f'''{x}''')}"""
                                    for y, x in enumerate(item["strict_encoded"])
                                ]
                            )
                            try:
                                print(
                                    f"""{'Length'.ljust(20)}: {TC(f'''{itemlen}''').fg_purple.bg_black}\n{'Converted'.ljust(20)}: {concatitem}"""
                                )
                            except Exception:
                                print(
                                    f"""Problems during printing! Raw string: {concatitem!r}"""
                                )

                        if item["strict_bad"] is True:
                            concatitem = TC(
                                " ".join(item["strict_encoded"])
                            ).fg_red.bg_black
                            try:
                                print(
                                    f"""{'Length'.ljust(20)}: {TC(f'''{"None"}''').fg_red.bg_black}\n{'Converted'.ljust(20)}: {concatitem}"""
                                )
                            except Exception:
                                print(
                                    f"""Problems during printing! Raw string: {concatitem!r}"""
                                )
                print("")
            if "ignore_bad" in item and "ignore_encoded" in item:
                print(f'{"Mode".ljust(20)}: {TC("ignore").fg_yellow.bg_black}')

                if item["ignore_bad"] is False:
                    if isinstance(item["ignore_encoded"][0], tuple):

                        if item["ignore_bad"] is False:

                            try:
                                print(
                                    f"""{'Length'.ljust(20)}: {TC(f'''{item['ignore_encoded'][0][1]}''').bg_black.fg_lightgrey}\n{'Converted'.ljust(20)}: {TC(f'''{item['ignore_encoded'][0][0]}''').bg_black.fg_lightgrey}"""
                                )
                            except Exception:
                                print(
                                    f"""Problems during printing! Raw string: {item['ignore_encoded'][0][0]!r}"""
                                )

                print("")

            if "replace_bad" in item and "replace_encoded" in item:
                print(f'{"Mode".ljust(20)}: {TC("replace").fg_yellow.bg_black}')

                if item["replace_bad"] is False:
                    if isinstance(item["replace_encoded"][0], tuple):

                        if item["replace_bad"] is False:
                            try:
                                print(
                                    f"""{'Length'.ljust(20)}: {TC(f'''{item['replace_encoded'][0][1]}''').bg_black.fg_lightgrey}\n{'Converted'.ljust(20)}: {TC(f'''{item['replace_encoded'][0][0]}''').bg_black.fg_lightgrey}"""
                                )
                            except Exception:
                                print(
                                    f"""Problems during printing! Raw string: {item['replace_encoded'][0][0]!r}"""
                                )

            counter = counter + 1

        return self


if __name__ == "__main__":
    teststuff = b"""This is a test! 
    Hi there!
    A little test! """
    testfilename = "test_utf8.tmp"
    with open("test_utf8.tmp", mode="w", encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
        f.write(teststuff.decode("utf-8-sig"))
    codechecker = CodecChecker()
    codechecker.try_open_file(testfilename, readlines=2).print_results(
        pause_after_interval=1, items_per_interval=10
    )
    codechecker.try_open_file(testfilename).print_results()
    codechecker.try_convert_bytes(teststuff.decode("cp850").encode()).print_results(
        pause_after_interval=1, items_per_interval=10
    )
```

Or you simply run a script to replace all messed up characters. Since I am a German teacher, I have this problem frequently (encoding problems due to Umlaut). Here is a script to replace all characters (too big to post the script here): https://github.com/hansalemaos/LatinFixer/blob/main/__init__.py